# Click on the link (to download a file) using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Click on the link (to download a file) using Selenium. Tried xpath, element by text etc but didn't work. The element looks like this:

```
<span class="download-data-link"><a download="" target"_blank"="" style="cursor:pointer">Download file in csv format</a></span>
```

Error I am getting with xpath approach:

```
   downloadWithSelenium(currDate,fileName, fileLink)
  File "D:\code\portfolio\downloadWithSelenium.py", line 27, in downloadWithSelenium
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='historicalData']").click()
  File "C:\Users\susmeher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\susmeher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\susmeher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\susmeher\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible 
(Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181) 
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

...implies that the `xpath` used to identify the desired element was not visible.

### Solution

As per the HTML you have shared to identify and invoke `click()` on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- **LinkText** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Download file in csv format"))).click();
  ```
- **Xpath** :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='download-data-link']/a[contains(.,'Download file in csv format')]"))).click();
  ```